# Algorithms for tar and dump

Tags: algorithm, tar

I need to know how tar, dump, cpio works. what is the algorithm behind all these program. How does tar traverse a file system tree, etc. Where can I get the details?

Thanks

Comment: For a start, read the manpages and/or read the source code (e.g. of the GNU versions) of these tools; then come back to SO once you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to know in detail how they work, you can download the source code of [GNU `tar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/), [GNU `cpio`](http://www.gnu.org/s/cpio/) and [ext2 `dump`](http://dump.sourceforge.net/).

If you have specific, more high-level question about one of them, you can ask a new question about that.